# finding probabilities in a column for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
state   class
   A      0
   B      1
   C      1
   A      0
   A      1
   B      1
   A      0
   A      1
   C      1
   C      0
```

and im trying to find the probability for each of the unique value found in state as per output class such that the resultant output would b like:

```
State_0   State_1    Class
  3/5       2/5         0
  0/2       2/2         1
  1/3       2/3         1
  3/5       2/5         0
  3/5       2/5         1
  0/2       2/2         1
  3/5       2/5         0
  3/5       2/5         1
  1/3       2/3         1
  1/3       2/3         0
```

logic used to find these values: 
A,B,C are the unique values in state, and A occurs total 5 times out of which 3 times when class is 0 and 2 times when class is 1.
I am able to find the state_0 and state_1 value for a single state like A,B or C but not able to apply it on whole dataset.

Could anyone please help here or suggest..

Comment: how did you calculate the class column.  also you missing the index column A,B, etc for the rows.   It is difficult to infer what was counted without it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize=0`, then add prefix to columns by  [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and add to original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.join(pd.crosstab(df['state'], df['class'], normalize=0).add_prefix('State_'), 
              on='state')
print (df1)
  state  class   State_0   State_1
0     A      0  0.600000  0.400000
1     B      1  0.000000  1.000000
2     C      1  0.333333  0.666667
3     A      0  0.600000  0.400000
4     A      1  0.600000  0.400000
5     B      1  0.000000  1.000000
6     A      0  0.600000  0.400000
7     A      1  0.600000  0.400000
8     C      1  0.333333  0.666667
9     C      0  0.333333  0.666667
```

Last if need filter some columns:

```
df2 = df1.reindex(['State_0','State_1','class'], axis=1)
print (df2)
    State_0   State_1  class
0  0.600000  0.400000      0
1  0.000000  1.000000      1
2  0.333333  0.666667      1
3  0.600000  0.400000      0
4  0.600000  0.400000      1
5  0.000000  1.000000      1
6  0.600000  0.400000      0
7  0.600000  0.400000      1
8  0.333333  0.666667      1
9  0.333333  0.666667      0
```

Answer (score 0):

brute force using groupby

```
state=['A','B','C','A','A','B','A','A','C','C']     
myclass=[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
df=pd.DataFrame({'state':state,'class':myclass})
groupedCount=df.groupby('state').count().values
groupedSum=df.groupby(['state']).sum().values

for key,row in df.iterrows():
    a_class=row['class']
    a_state=row['state']
    stateCount=groupedCount[a_class][0]
    zeroSum=groupedCount[a_class][0]-groupedSum[a_class][0]
    oneSum=groupedSum[a_class][0]
    if a_class==0:
        df.loc[key,'State_'+str(a_class)]=str(zeroSum)+'/'+str(stateCount)
        df.loc[key,'State_1']=str(stateCount-zeroSum)+'/'+str(stateCount)
    else:
        df.loc[key,'State_'+str(a_class)]=str(oneSum)+'/'+str(stateCount)
        df.loc[key,'State_0']=str(stateCount-oneSum)+'/'+str(stateCount)
    print(a_class,a_state,groupedSum[a_class][0],groupedCount[a_class][0])

     print(df.head)
```